# Does changing a creatures type change its traits?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

I was wondering: If I change, say a vermin into an dragon with the half-dragon template, does its traits change? The template says that the half-dragon retains all special qualities of the base creature.

1) If a creature lists vermin traits as a special quality, does it keep these traits? Are they replaced by dragon traits?

2) Does a half-dragon even gain dragon traits? It says nowhere they gain them, or do they get them by virtue of being a dragon?

3) How about the 'mindless' trait of vermin. Since half-dragon grants +2 Intelligence, you can't have that trait anymore, can you?

I hope to get some answers soon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short Answer: Yes, the traits (*not* features) should change as they are inherited from the Creature Type. "Special Qualities" would apply to anything the base creature has that isn't a part of the creature type, such as breath attacks or spellcasting ability.

Long Answer: Here's the way I would do it:

1) and 2) As the half-dragon template changes creature type to *Dragon*, you [look up that creature type](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/typesSubtypes.htm#dragonType) and apply the relevant traits (but *not* features).  As this has replaced the creature type *Vermin*, you ought to be removing any traits gained from that (unless they were also in *Dragon*) - however, see 4).

3) If something applied in the template invalidates a previous trait, such as +2 intelligence taking it over the limit for mindless, then remove the trait.  In this particular case though, the creature has stopped being *Vermin* and is instead *Dragon* and therefore loses that trait anyway.  If you really wanted a mindless half-dragon vermin, see 4).

4) Optionally, use common sense to tweak if doing any of the above results in it feeling wrong.  If in your game's universe you feel a specific half-dragon creature should not have certain dragon traits, remove them.  If something was changed to be partially something else via a template, you may want to keep some or all of the traits that any change in Creature Type has removed.  For example, you may want your half-Dragon-Vermin to still be Mindless to represent having physical dragon features with a vermin mind (in which case you could add that trait back in and remove the +2 to intelligence).

For clarifications, see http://www.d20srd.org/srd/improvingMonsters.htm#templates (thanks @Tridus !)

Comment: Thanks for this clear answer! You see, I was confused because a few monsters had 'vermin traits' listed in their statblock. I thought it might carry over.

Comment: [Under the normal changing type rules](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/improvingMonsters.htm#templates), traits are from the new type but features are not:  "Unless a template indicates otherwise, the new creature has the traits of the new type but the features of the original type. "