# What happens when a creature with Racial Hit Dice changes creature type?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, monsters, character-advancement, hit-dice

The specific example I'm working with is a creature with RHD who takes the Human Heritage feat... and then advances by HD.

The creature retains all the traits of its previous type (so far so good), but what happens to its existing RHD? Do they change to the new type, or stay the same? The SRD says:

> ...but most templates that change Hit Dice change only the creature’s original HD and leave class Hit Dice unchanged.

However, this is in the context of whether class HD change when there is already an HD change happening, so I don't know if it should generalize to "HD changing is the default".

If the creature then advances by gaining more HD, I assume that all the new HD would be of the new type, but I'm open to peoples' opinions on this as well.

Bridging the two questions, there's also an argument to be made that since Human Heritage is a 1st level only feat, *all* RHD are acquired after it is taken, and should thus be of the Humanoid type.

Comment: "Does changing a creatures type change its traits?" (https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/35053/does-changing-a-creatures-type-change-its-traits) and "When a creature's type changes to undead, what happens to its hit points?" (https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/86495/when-a-creatures-type-changes-to-undead-what-happens-to-its-hit-points) both have some relation to this question.

Comment: RE: "If the creature then advances by gaining more HD." How? I mean, in the game, how is this pre-existing creature that has discovered his human heritage then gaining racial Hit Dice? Or are racial Hit Dice being treated as class levels that can be taken? [This exchange](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/110818/8610) to the contrary, I've usually seen racial Hit Dice treated exclusively as a DM thing to make a monster beefier and not a PC option. Can the question detail the precise situation—the monster, the classes, and the advancement scheme?

Comment: @HeyICanChan Ah, in this case I *am* basically the DM. More specifically, I'm designing this monster for a Halloween themed contest over on Giant in the Playground, and want to make sure I'm getting the rules right.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question because it relates to templates, and Human Heritage is a feat, but since it seems you're using the template rules as a guide, this might be useful: "Unless a template indicates otherwise, the new creature has the traits of the new type but the features of the original type." The features of a type are it's HD, BAB, Saves, and Skills. The traits are everything else.